# Get disk time in percentage in windows

Tags: c#, .net, disk, performancecounter

I have the following scenario, I want to get the utilization (Disk Time) per disk in percent.
Unfortunately it always returns the value 0 when I switch through the instances, why?

Here is my code:

```cs
while (true)
{
    foreach (var disk in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
    {
        var diskInstances = diskCounterCategory.GetInstanceNames();
        var diskInstance = string.Empty;

        foreach(var instance in diskInstances)
        {
            if (instance.Contains(disk.Name[0].ToString()))
            {
                var tesst = new PerformanceCounter("PhysicalDisk", "% Disk Time", instance);
                var tesst3 = (uint)tesst.NextSample().BaseValue;
                Console.WriteLine(tesst3);
            }
        }
    }

    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}
```

Comment: Do you get/show different results when you view those counters using PerfMon?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Here is the solution I came up with:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Setting up the counters...");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-US");
            Dictionary<string, PerformanceCounter> diskCounters = new Dictionary<string, PerformanceCounter>();
            PerformanceCounterCategory logicalDiskCategory = PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories().FirstOrDefault(x => x.CategoryName.Equals("LogicalDisk"));
            if (logicalDiskCategory == null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ERROR: Category not found!");
                return;
            }
            string[] diskInstances = logicalDiskCategory.GetInstanceNames();
            foreach (string diskName in diskInstances)
            {
                PerformanceCounter counter = logicalDiskCategory.GetCounters(diskName).FirstOrDefault(x => x.CounterName.Equals("% Disk Time"));
                if (counter != null)
                {
                    diskCounters.Add(diskName, counter);
                }
            }
            while (true)
            {
                Console.Clear();
                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, PerformanceCounter> pair in diskCounters)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine($"Time: {DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss")}\t| Disk: {pair.Key}\t| Utilisation: {pair.Value.NextValue()}%");
                }
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Explanation:**

When we create a counter on our own, like this:

```
new PerformanceCounter("LogicalDisk", "% Disk Time", "C:");
```

it will constantly return 0. I myself don’t know why this is so, but if we take `PerformanceCounterCategory` from the `PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories()` array and then find the desired counter in it through `GetCounters(DiskName)`, the counter will start to produce non-zero results!

But there is one issue in here. If you try to check the names of the Categories you got from the `PerformanceCounterCategory.GetCategories()` they will be localized, so it is very important to set the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` to `en-US` before accessing it, because in other case it will not work at all or will not work on others computers.

Hope this helped)